# SIFT algorithm in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sift

I am looking for a Matlab implementation of the SIFT algorithm.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not quite sure what you're after, but there are several MATLAB implementations of the SIFT algorithm available:

http://www.vlfeat.org/

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18441

Answer (score 4):

There's a demo executable available from David Lowe's page: http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/keypoints/

There are windows and linux executables for performing the SIFT extraction, and matlab functions for doing matching.